# How Solr indexes documents?

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene

I'm new to Solr and I want to understand exactly how it indexes documents.

Let's say I have a 100 MB document (document1) full of text. The text is not structured, it's just raw text. I send that document to Solr in order to be indexed.

As far as I understood, Lucene will parse the document, extract all the words, based on the default schema (let's assume we're using the default schema), and create an index that is basically a mapping between a word and a list of documents, like so:

*word1* -> **[document1]**

*word2* -> **[document1]**

etc

Now, if I want to search for the word *"word1"*, Solr will give me the entire 100 MB document that contains the word *"word1"*, **correct**?

Please correct me if I'm wrong, I need to understand exactly how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You described most of the indexing part kinda okay, at least at high level. The reason, why you getting all your document back - it is because your field is a [stored](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/defining-fields.html#DefiningFields-OptionalFieldTypeOverrideProperties) one in your Solr schema (which is true by default at least)

This means, that apart from having postings list of
word1 -> doc1, doc3
word2 -> doc2, doc3
etc.

Solr/Lucene also stores the original content of the field, so it will be able to return it back to you. You could either explictily turn it off by saying `stored=false` in your schema or by filtering it out in [fl](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html#CommonQueryParameters-Thefl_FieldList_Parameter) section and just request `fl=id` (or something similar)

If you would like to return part of the document only, around searched ones, you could do that by using [Solr Highlighting feature](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/highlighting.html).  Highlighting in Solr allows fragments of documents that match the user’s query to be included with the query response.

Comment: okay, thank you for the answer. Is there a way get back only a part of the document? For example the words around the searched one, or something like that? I guess this is not possible because of the way Solr is built (returning documents)